# Math Equation Using % / Modulus / Remainder

Tags: modular-arithmetic

So in javascript programming you get a % / Modulus / Remainder operator. It divides a number by the max amount it can be divided by (dropping decimals), and then returns what is left after this max division. Here are some practical examples:

```
6 % 3 = 0 (because 6 / 3 = 2, then 6 - (3 x 2) = 0)
10 % 4 = 2 (because 10 / 4 = 2.5, then 10 - (4 x 2) = 2)
33 % 6 = 3 (because 33 / 6 = 5.5, then 33 - (6 x 5) = 3)
```

Now my problem is I am trying to figure out a math problem and I think the % is throwing me off. Have a look at this:

```
46 * 2 % 67 = 25
x  * y % z  = a
```

Now in this above equation, how do I get x? When I have:

```
y = 2
z = 67
a = 25
```

Comment: are you sure $46 * 2 \% 67=32$?

Comment: $(46\cdot2)\bmod67\ne32$ !

Comment: $46 \times 2 \cong 25 \pmod{67}$, but is not congruent to $32 \pmod{67}$.

Comment: Ah extremely sorry about this everyone! Got confused while creating the answer. I updated to the correct value (25)

Comment: Note that the `%` operator in programming languages often works differently from the modulo operation favored by mathematicians when one or both operands are negative.